# How can we create a table with condition on columns?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a table with condition :

```
CREATE TABLE abc
(
firstsem_marks NVARCHAR(100),
secondsem_marks NVARCHAR(100),
percentage NVARCHAR(100) CHECK((secondsem_marks-firstsem_marks/firstsem_marks))*100,
name NVARCHAR(100)
)
```

Can anyone please look into or tell the other way to do it .
i want to create a table in which i can render the percentage according to the two sem marks.

Comment: If `percenatage` is just derived from the values of other columns, you should be looking at a *[computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300.aspx)*.

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE abc
(
    firstsem_marks float,
    secondsem_marks float,
    percentage as 100 * (secondsem_marks - firstsem_marks)/firstsem_marks,
    name NVARCHAR(100)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Computed column is the solution. But datatype should be float for percentage calculation

```
CREATE TABLE abc
(
    firstsem_marks FLOAT,
    secondsem_marks FLOAT,
    percentage AS ((secondsem_marks-firstsem_marks/firstsem_marks))*100,
    name NVARCHAR(100)
)
```